# Dialog standardButtons position

Tags: qt, qml

I want to make Dialog with only 1 button ("OK"). But when I use "standardButtons: Dialog.Ok" it positions it to the right. How it may be positioned in the middle? I would like to keep current button dimensions.

[image]

I've tried to use DialogButtonBox, and also Rectangle and Buttons in footer, but every time it not worked, or look like a mess

Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        id: button
        text: qsTr("Button")
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onClicked: dialog.open()
    }

    Dialog {
        id: dialog
        modal: true
        font.bold: true
        title: "WARNING!!!"
        Text {
            id: dialogMessage
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \nsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
        parent: Overlay.overlay
        x: parent.width/2 - width/2
        y: parent.height/2 - height/2

        standardButtons: Dialog.Ok
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Dialog {
        id: dialog
        x: parent.width/2 - width/2
        y: parent.height/2 - height/2
        parent: Overlay.overlay
        modal: true
        font.bold: true
        title: "WARNING!!!"
        standardButtons: Dialog.Ok
        visible: true

        Text {
            id: dialogMessage
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \nsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }

        // Declare your own DialogButtonBox.
        footer: DialogButtonBox {
            alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        }

        // Assign it declaratively.
//        Binding {
//            target: dialog.footer
//            property: "alignment"
//            value: Qt.AlignHCenter
//        }

        // Assign it imperatively.
//        Component.onCompleted: dialog.footer.alignment = Qt.AlignHCenter
    }
}
```

I've left the other ones commented out to illustrate that you only need one of these approaches.

Note that you can't just do:

```
footer.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
```

because the type of the `footer` property is `Item`, not `DialogButtonBox`, and `Item` doesn't have an `alignment` property.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Column Layout`, it will keep the dialog in shape. Also use both `Layout.alignment` and `alignment` property in the `DialogButtonBox` - the dialog will look just as You wish:

```
Dialog {
        id: dialog
        modal: true
        font.bold: true
        visible: true
        title: "WARNING!!!"
        ColumnLayout {
            Text {
                id: dialogMessage
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, \nsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
            }

            DialogButtonBox{
                standardButtons: DialogButtonBox.Ok
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter

                onAccepted: dialog.close()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I accepted @Mitch answer because it's less code to write

Comment: Great to hear that we've helped! :)